# Add new variable to specific position in dataframe without specifying a numbered position

Tags: r, variables

In Stata, I can create a variable after or before another one. E.g. gen age=., after(sex)

I would like to do the same in R. Is it possible?

My database has 300 variables, so I don't want to count it to discover its numbered position and also I might change from time to time.

Comment: Can you explain what `gen age=., after(sex)` does?

Comment: It creates the variable age with all missing values in a column after the column sex.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
library(tibble) 

data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(1,2,3), c = c(1,2,3))

add_column(data, d = "", .after = "b")

# a b d c
# 1 1   1
# 2 2   2
# 3 3   3
```

Or another way could be:

```
data.frame(append(data, list(d = ""), after = match("b", names(data))))
```

Comment: Thank you, Matt. Unfortunately, I don't have "tibble" installed in my secure environment, but I'll ask the IT to add this package for me.

Comment: @mariana, the second way in my answer does not require `tibble`.

Comment: I've done: data.frame(append(patients$birth_kg, list(patients$birth_kg = birth_gr/1000), after = match (patients$birth_gr))) Where patients is my dataset, birth_kg the variable I'm creating and birth_gr the variable that already exists. However, it hasn't worked.

Comment: Try `data.frame(append(patients, list(birth_kg = patients$birth_gr/1000), after = match ("birth_gr", names(patients))))`

Answer (score 0):

First add the new column to the end of your data frame.  Then, find the index of the column after which you want that new column to actually appear, and interpolate it:

```
df$new_col <- ...
index <- match("col_before", names(df))
df <- df[, c(names(df)[c(1:index)], "new_col", names(df)[c((index+1):(ncol(df)-1))])]
```

Sample:

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c(1:3), v2=c(4:6), v3=c(7:9))
df$new_col <- c(7,7,7)
index <- match("v2", names(df))
df <- df[, c(names(df)[c(1:index)], "new_col", names(df)[c((index+1):(ncol(df)-1))])]
df

  v1 v2 new_col v3
1  1  4       7  7
2  2  5       7  8
3  3  6       7  9
```

Comment: Many thanks, Tim. The code seems complicated to a beginner like me, but it has worked.

Comment: I've done that. However, as I'm a new member, it doesn't take my votes into account. I'm sorry.